# Can linked objects with physics constraints interact with other objects?

Tags: animation, physics

(Newbie to list:  1st post.  Hello everyone)

Specific question:  How to make linked objects with physics constraints interact with newly created objects.

I am trying to use Blender2.8 to animate off road vehicles driving over terrain.

Each vehicle is created in it’s own .blend file, with suspension and wheels made using physics constraints (e.g. motors, hinges).  The vehicle physics work fine within their own .blend files.

When linked into a overall .blend file, these vehicles either pass through local objects (when the local objects are in their own collection), or linked objects won’t move (when I placed everything in a single collection).   Note: I am creating a rigidbodyworld to include the relevant collection, but it’s not working quite right.

What is the best strategy for doing this? For a static object many approaches work - but these are physics-enabled objects which need to bounce and roll properly within the overall scene.   I tried different methods: link, append, instances, proxies.  I would like to use link because then I can go back and edit the individual vehicles and everything will update.  Does this make sense?

Basically I’m unable to have the linked objects with their physics constraints properly interact with newly created objects - even when I put everything in the same collection, and enable a rigidbodyworld.    That’s the question.

( I tried to find other posts on this question and found some useful info.  Sorry if this has already been answered.  Using Blender 2.8 2019-01-12)

Thank you for any suggestions.
Matt